# AVERAGEIFS ERROR "Divide by Zero"

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to calculate an average # days an account has been open if all 3 specific conditions are met.

Average range: **R6:R102**

Conditions:

- A6:A102 = "x"
- S6:S102 = "* EWS *" (contain part of EWS)
- B6:B102 = past 3 years
  For last condition, the easiest solution was to put a formula in A3 (where A3= `=TODAY()-1095`) and then reference it in my `AVERAGEIFS` formula.

`=AVERAGEIFS(R6:R102, A6:A102, "x", S6:S102, "*EWS*", B6:B102, ">A3")`

Formula worked fine until I added condition #3. Now, I get a `DIVIDE BY ZERO` error. Why does it give me an error? Should I be making the last condition a date between today and 3yrs ago?

appreciate any insight you can provide. thank you!

Comment: Try _">"&A3_ as last condition.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, this works! user0 also came up with a solution that got rid of using cell A3. both solutions work great. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`=TODAY()-1095`** doesn't count for leap years etc. so:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(R4:R102, A4:A102, "x", 
                     S4:S102, "*EWS*", 
                     B4:B102, ">"&MONTH(TODAY())&"/"&DAY(TODAY())&"/"&YEAR(TODAY())-3)
```

Comment: you're the best, @user0! thank you yet again :)